# Can't access htdocs on different machine LAN

Tags: apache, centos, xampp

I'm having a problem in my web-server (centOS 7). I've set up xampp and I want to access htdocs from a different machine. However I get connection expired.

I'm connecting on port 80 and I've checked `# netstat -nlp`:

```
tcp6  0  0 :::80  :::* LISTEN  10366/httpd
```

and `# netstat -tul`:

```
tcp6 0  0 :::80  :::*  LISTEN  0
```

I've also checked httpd.conf and it contains:

```
Listen 80
```

I've set a firewall exception and I still can't access htdocs. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

EDIT: I've also checked it the port was opened using `# telnet myserver.com 80` and I managed to connect to the server using port 80.

EDIT2: After re-setting the firewall restrictions, and enabling any LAN user to access the server, the connection finally happened.

Comment: What is the `ServerName`  set in the Apache config?

Comment: I wanted to access the localhost, but after a lot of pain I've finally made it. Not exactly sure how though.